# How do I access Windows credentials?

Tags: vb.net, credentials

(Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager)
How would I access Windows credentials from a Visual Basic form? This is not for hacking purposes, simply knowledge and so I can recover my OWN passwords. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't recover plain password through .net, what you could get is a security token for a given user/password or logged user.

Comment: But isn't Windows Credentials what most logging viruses use?